# Iterar un arreglo que llene primero renglones, columna por columna

Tags: javascript, array

estoy intentando iterar un arreglo por columnas y renglones, tengo mi arreglo:

arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

mis loops :

```
for(var c = 1; c < cols; c++){
   for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        }
      }
```

quiero que mi arreglo quede asi:

```
[1 4 7
 2 5 8
 3 6 9]
```

ahorita me sigue llenando por columnas primero, hay alguna solución a esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo para que lo acomodes a tu caso:

```js
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
newArr = [];

for(var c = 1; c < 4; c++){
   for(var r = 0; r < 3; r++){
     newArr.push((3*r) + c);
   }
}

console.log(newArr);
```